# JSON fetching image is really slow iOS Swift, What to do make it faster?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a Get request using Alamofire to fetch some data and image URL. And showing the url as image into TableView. The problem is image is loading really slow and the tableview seems really laggy. Can someone suggest me where i am doing wrong or the best way to do this task.
here is my code:-

```
func getTheData() {
    print("Hello dear ::::::::::-\(accesstoken as Any)")
    guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accesstoken") else {
        return
    }
    let headers = [
        "x-access-token": token,
    ]
    Alamofire.request("http://192.168.80.21:3204/api/product/get_all_products", headers: headers).responseJSON { [self]
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let myresponse = try? JSON(data: response.data!)
            print(myresponse as Any)
            let resultArray = myresponse
            self.array_product_name.removeAll()
            
            for i in resultArray!.arrayValue{
                let product_name = i["product_name"].stringValue
                self.array_product_name.append(product_name)
                
                let product_price = i["price"].stringValue
                self.array_product_price.append(product_price)
                
                let product_image  = i["image_url"].stringValue
                self.array_product_image.append(product_image)
                print("test :-\(product_image)")
                self.image_array = product_image
                print("Test1:- \(self.image_array)")
                    }
                
        case .failure(_):
            print(Error.self)
        }
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

TableView code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell

    cell?.cellLbl.text = array_product_name[indexPath.row]
    cell?.productPrice.text = array_product_price[indexPath.row]

        if let url = URL(string: image_array){
                   do {
                       let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                    cell?.productImageLbl.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    print("Test2:- \(data)")
                       
                   }catch let err {
                       print(" Error : \(err.localizedDescription)")
                   }
        }
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: `Data(contentsOf: url)`: That's a synchrone call, it means its BLOCKING the current thread (it doesn't go on the next line until it downloaded the data), since you are doing it in the main thread which handles the UI, that's blocking the whole UI app (and the app in general). Instead, you need to do it like Alamofire did in background. Either manually with URLSession, or using Alamofire+Image (since you use Alamofire), or SDWebImage, KingFisher, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load image asynchronously. You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) library which can additionally do caching as well. The usage is simple.

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) Its has downloading and caching images from the api.

```
var  imageUIView  = UIImageView()
let url = URL(string:"https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png")
imageUIView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```